# General versions for quadrics of Pascal and Brianchon theorems

Tags: analytic-geometry, projective-geometry

I am looking for a generalization to quadrics (with proofs) of Pascal's and Brianchon's theorems. It´s for Three dimensional analytical geometry.

I would be very thankful if you could point me towards one.

Answer (score 1):

Tried to add this as a comment, but comments not working right now:
The question is an exact duplicate of [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1207089/quadric-generalizations-of-pascal-and-brianchons-theorems).

But, anyway, start with the classical geometry texts. Salmon, Sommerville, and books like that.

[Sommerville, Analytical Geometry of Three Dimensions.](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00085DFRW)

[Snyder & Sisam, Analytical Geometry of Space](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00AV5K27K)

[Salmon, A Treatise on the Analytic Geometry of Three Dimensions](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/140695893X)